# SimpleDateFormat String

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have this code block where argument to `dateFormat.format` will always be a `string` thats why I did `.toString()` here. I am getting error "Cannot format given Object as a Date".

Is there any way to do this ? Note that string is coming from database I used new Date() as a sample here.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
String sCertDate = dateFormat.format(new Date().toString());
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to achieve ultimately

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[DateFormat#format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) accepts a Date, not a string.

Use

```
String sCertDate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

If you have a string coming from the database that is a specific format and you want to convert into a date, you should use the [parse](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) method.

@Sonesh - Let us assume you have a string in the database that happens to represent a Date ( might be better to store the object in the database as dates? ) , then you would first `parse` it to the format you wanted and then `format` it to the string format you wanted.

```
// Assumes your date is stored in db with format 08/01/2011
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatOfStringInDB = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date d1 = dateFormatOfStringInDB.parse(yourDBString);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatYouWant = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
String sCertDate = dateFormatYouWant.format(d1);
```

Comment: @Evan the `parse()` method accepts a String. the `format()` method accepts a Date.

Comment: @Sonesh If you need the date in a different format then, yes, you'll have to parse and then format it in the way you want.

Answer (score 6):

There are two applications of `SimpleDateFormat`:

- parse a string - when you have a date represented as string, and you want to get the corresponding `Date` object. Then use `dateFormat.parse(string)`
- format a date - when you have a `Date` object and you want to format it in a specific way (usually in order to show it to a user). In that case use `dateFormat.format(date)`

The two methods are reciprocal - one takes a date and returns a string, and the other takes a string and returns a date.

For your particular case, perhaps you need `.parse(..)`. But note that every 'self-respecting' database driver should have an option to return a `Date` rather than some string representation. If you happen to be storing dates as string in the DB - don't do that. Use the native date type.

Comment: I tried to use parse getting error . "Unparseable date: "Mon Aug 22 16:10:16 GMT+00:00 2011"" . SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
  Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(new Date().toString());
  String sCertDate = dateFormat.format(parsedDate);

Comment: well, obviously the format you specify and the format of the date are rather different.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to read a Date with one String format and output it to another String format, you need 2 formatters, for example:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
String output = outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(input));
```

Comment: I tried this  outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(new Date().toString()));  And error is "Unparseable date: "Mon Aug 22 16:10:16 GMT+00:00 2011""

Comment: @Sonesh you need an adequate Date format to parse "Mon Aug 22 16:10:16 GMT+00:00 2011". "yyyy-MM-dd" parses dates like "2010-11-25".