# Unable to create local windows directory structure using Selenium

Tags: javascript, eclipse, windows, selenium

Trying to follow the examples outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669754/how-to-create-a-folder-in-c-directory-and-need-to-save-the-screenshot-in-that-di) and [here](http://selenium-by-arun.blogspot.com/2014/08/260-creating-folders-using-mkdir-method.html) to ensure that the directory I'm putting my results reports in is always present for a given user.

```
new File(sampleFolder).mkdir();
```

Where sampleFolder is showing in the Eclipse debugger as 
    "C:\Users\CurrentUser\workspace\Automation_Framework//Reports//output//TestCasesHtmlReports//"

and is populated from the variable definition

```
public static String sampleFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//Reports//output//TestCasesHtmlReports//";
```

However when I run the script the folder structure is NOT being created, any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to run Eclipse as an administrator?

Comment: Your should change '//' to '\\' in windows.

Comment: @SureshKoya isn't it '\'? You can also create with absolute path `C:/Users/CurrentUser/workspace/Automation_Framework/Reports/output/TestCasesHtmlReports/`

Comment: You cannot just input a single backslash. To input a backslash in the path you need to escape it with another backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two changes:

> Change 1:
>
> You are inputting the slashes incorrectly. I am not sure how the '//' gets parsed. On windows the "\" gets resolved to a "\" because the first backslash is used as a escape character.

You could compose the File path in a standard way as below. `File.separator` is Platform dependent default name-separator character as String. For windows, it’s ‘\’ and for unix it’s ‘/’

```
 public static String sampleFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Reports" + File.separator + "output" + File.separator+ "TestCasesHtmlReports";
```

Information about Java separator's in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746419/file-separator-vs-file-pathseparator).

> Change 2:
>
> You need to use `File.mkdirs` instead of `File.mkdir`

The problem is with the API you are using.
[File.mkdir](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()) Javadoc reads

> public boolean mkdir()
>
> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname.
>
> Returns:
>
> true if and only if the directory was created; false otherwise

[File.mkdirs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) Javadoc reads

> public boolean mkdirs()
>
> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.
>
> Returns:
>
> true if and only if the directory was created, along with all necessary parent directories; false otherwise

Comment: Just got back to this, I restructured the variable initiator to mirror your sample above, still no path being created, any ideas? The path IS now appearing correctly in the Eclipse output: C:\Users\CurrentUser\workspace\Automation_Framework\XSLT_Reports\output\TestCasesHtmlReports

Comment: Oh for the love of.... was using mkdir() instead of mkdirs(). Working now and learned something today (File.Separator), thanks!