# Why SimpleDateFormat does not apply specified date pattern?

Tags: java

I have following code to format a date, but the output does not match with the pattern.

```
try{
        String date = "2014-11-1T12:14:00";
        Date convertedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(date);
        System.err.println(convertedDate.toString());
        }catch(ParseException p){
            System.err.println(p.getMessage());
        }
```

**Output**

```
Sat Nov 01 00:00:00 EST 2014
```

Comment: So you don't know whether it's the output or the exception handler that is printing...

Comment: read this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150231/simpledateformat-string

Comment: `Date` has no concept of format, it is only a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch.  Instead, you need to format the `Date` value to a `String` using the desired format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are questioning why you don't get the time, that's because your format doesn't include it. I suggest you use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"` to match your input and `"yyyy-MM-dd"` when you call [`DateFormat#format(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29),

```
try {
  String date = "2014-11-1T12:14:00";
  Date convertedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(date);
  System.out.println(convertedDate.toString());
  // Per your comment you wanted to `format()` it like -
  System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(convertedDate));
} catch (ParseException p) {
  System.err.println(p.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: The question is that why my format is yyyy-MM-dd but the output is not 2014-11-01

Comment: @Jack Edited. You did want to format it.

Answer (score 1):

For what you described below in our conversation, you can simply do this:

```
System.err.println((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).format(convertedDate));
```

Comment: The question is that why my format is yyyy-MM-dd but the output is not 2014-11-01